# How to sort Datasnapshot using OrderByChild() from cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I´m working with cloud functions and trying to get a DataSnapshot with the children of the **server** node sorted in ascending order by the value on the **lastTimeUsed** inner child. I´m using orderByChild but I´m getting a dataSnapshot that is not sorted as I need it.

I read the information [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sort_data)

[image]

Here is part of the cloud function

```
  var serversSorted = serversRef.orderByChild('{serverId}/lastTimeUsed').on("value", function(snapshot) {

    snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
      console.log(" Server is " + data.val().lastTimeUsed);
    });
  });
```

And these are the logs from google cloud
[image]

Comment: Priorities are not a useful concept in modern Firebase Realtime Database usage anymore, and are just kept around for backwards compatibility. Aside from that I am not clear what you're trying to do, and (importantly) what problem you're having while implementing it. I'd recommend including the [minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces where you stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question.

Comment: Hi, I just edited my question, I will really appreciate your help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `orderByChild('{serverId}/lastTimeUsed')` syntax you used is not something that Firebase recognizes. So you're in effect ordering on a non-existing property, which explains that the results come in the order of their keys.

The property way to retrieve all child nodes of `servers` by the value of their `lastTimeUsed` property is:

```
firebase.database.ref("servers").orderByChild('lastTimeUsed')
```